# a describing noun + noun

Tags: grammar

```
He is a liar man.
```

> The two may sound ok but are perhaps NOT accurate because of:
> Subj+ V+ noun+ noun

I think the correct would be either:

**He is a lying man.**

or

**He is a liar.**

Answer (score 2):

Not a grammar error, but unidiomatic (and therefore "wrong")

Many uses of attributive nouns are short idioms.  So "chicken soup" is fine but "liar man" is not. You'd just say "He's a liar". No need for "man".

Comment: You certainly could use "He's a lying…" but the following noun will rarely be printable in a PG publication ;))